# Whitespace replacing plus sign in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have this regular expression:

```
name=\"javax.faces.FormSignature\" value="(.+?)"
```

that will extract the value I need to pass to a http request. My problem is, if this value happens to have a `+` or a `=` sign on it, Jmeter will replace them with a whitespace. That will fail my request. 
Has anyone seen this before? I've tried with xpath extractor and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this shappens in next request that uses the RegExp extracted value then uncheck **Encode** checkbox in Parameters Table.

See [Send Parameters With the Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why Jmeter could be doing that?